How to build a php function that will check a irregular series?
This is a irregular series (10%7 = 3, 11%7 = 4 ----- 15%7=1)
3  
4
5
6
0
1

What will be the next integer of this series using php?
Expected output 16%7 =2.
My try. It is considering 7. But I don't want to consider 7
<?php

function findNextInSeries($series, $divisor) {
    // Determine the last remainder
    $lastValue = end($series);
    $lastRemainder = $lastValue % $divisor;

    // Find the next remainder in the sequence
    $nextRemainder = ($lastRemainder + 1) % $divisor;

    // Iterate to find the next number in the sequence
    for ($i = $lastValue + 1; ; $i++) {
        if ($i % $divisor == $nextRemainder) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
}

// Given series
$series = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
$divisor = 7;

// Find the next integer in the series
$nextValue = findNextInSeries($series, $divisor);

echo "The next integer in the series is: $nextValue";
?>


Just return $nextRemainder. The loop is unnecessary.

The series is also not needed, just the last number in the series.

In what way is the series "irregular"? It just seem to be the fairly predictable result of dividing one number by another. And the numbers you're dividing simply increase by 1 each time...why do you need code to predict that? Perhaps you didn't explain it fully?

It is considering 7. But I don't want to consider 7...it's not clear what you mean by this or what 7 has to do with it (other than that being the divisor every time). Your code currently returns 16, which is the next number of the series of numbers to divide by. But in terms of it returning the answer 2, which is the next number in the series of answers to the division calculation, you just need to return $nextRemainder, as mentioned above. https://3v4l.org/ThQdH . Surely that's more useful than returning 16? Is there anything else we've missed?

You're overcomplicating this. You just need to get the next number in the series, and return its remainder. There's no need for $lastRemainder or the iteration.
function findNextInSeries($series, $divisor) {
    $lastValue = end($series);
    return ($lastValue + 1) % $divisor;
}

